# How to get raw response from .NET force.com toolkit when using QueryAsync

Tags: .net, httpresponse, force.com-toolkit-for-net

I am struggling to find out why my query throws an exception when I do a specific query. Is there a way to see the raw response from Salesforce or .NET?
Query string in itemQueryString is running correctly using workbench so I have ruled out query string problem.

Here is my code:

```
try{
    var results = forceClient.QueryAsync<JObject>(itemQueryString).Result;
    //do something...
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Error while querying items " + e.ToString());
}
```

Here is the exception

```
"System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while 
parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.\r\n   at 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n   at 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()\r\n   at 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.
ReadForType(JsonReadrr reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean 
hasConverter)\r\n   at 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.
Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean 
checkAdditionalContent)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.
DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\r\n   at 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, 
JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, 
JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at 
Salesforce.Common.ServiceHttpClient.<HttpGetAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n   --
- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean 
includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()\r\n   at 
ReportDataManager.PopulateItems(ItemQueryString) in 
ReportDataManager.cs:line 39\r\n---> (Inner Exception #0) 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while 
parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.\r\n   at 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n   at 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()\r\n   at 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.
ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean 
hasConverter)\r\n   at 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.
Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean 
checkAdditionalContent)\r\n   at 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type 
objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String 
value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, 
JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at 
Salesforce.Common.ServiceHttpClient.<HttpGetAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()<---\r\n"
```

Looks like it's returning unexpected result so query result cannot be parsed but I don't know how to get the raw response so I can see what is wrong with the query.

I tried to use system.net trace according to this blog; however, my trace is encrypted I cannot see the response. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/03/14/how-to-get-a-system-net-trace-of-your-c-web-job/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets go down the rabbit hole!

1. [ForceClient.QueryAsync](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/313c4b9106b9a0f9779d42514189addc713799a5/src/ForceToolkitForNET/ForceClient.cs#L38)
2. [JsonHttpClient.HttpGetAsync](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/313c4b9106b9a0f9779d42514189addc713799a5/src/CommonLibrariesForNET/JsonHttpClient.cs#L34)
3. [BaseHttpClient.HttpGetAsync](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/313c4b9106b9a0f9779d42514189addc713799a5/src/CommonLibrariesForNET/Internals/BaseHttpClient.cs#L46)

   ```
   protected async Task<string> HttpGetAsync(Uri uri)
   {
       var responseMessage = await HttpClient.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
       // ...
   }
   ```

If you were using the toolkit source directly rather than via nuget you could just grab the `responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` result as needed.

Otherwise your options are to:

1. Log the [HttpClient requests/responses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18924996/54026), or
2. Use a OS level tool to intercept the network traffic.

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointer. I used HttpClient instead of Forceclient to send the exact request. I was able to get HttpResponseMessage that contains the raw response. Finally I can see the error!